# How to install libjpeg-turbo8 on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libjpeg-turbo

As suggested by Google, I'm trying to get http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/ working on my Ubuntu server, but I'm getting the error:

"jpegtran: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

A Google search told me to install (via apt-get) libjpeg-turbo8, however apt-get can't find the package.  My own Ubuntu computer (running 12.0.10) can find the package just fine.

I tried installing http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/ with no luck.

Am I doing something wrong or have I missed something?  How do I get jpegtran working?

Answer (score 1):

This question may be old, but i was trying to run the glassfish updatetool and it failed because of the lack of the libjpeg library.

Steps i did take:

```
1. install libjpeg62:i386 (for 64 bit ubuntu amd6)
```

I hope it helps someone